# Massive logging on spring cloud stream

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-cloud-stream

in my logs there shows up a message like this every time I push something into the streamBridge to kafka

`Invoking function: streamBridge<org.springframework.messaging.Message<java.lang.Object>, org.springframework.messaging.Message<java.lang.Object>>with input type: org.springframework.messaging.Message<java.lang.Object>`

I'm using Spring-Boot 2.7.5, and spring-cloud-stream 3.2.7 including the kafka bindings in the same version. I cant find where to turn this of, doesnt seem to be able to control this with logback, as its only printed to the console and not to our logstash as every other message...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This logs is from s-c-function. What version do you use?

Comment: it has recently been addressed and is now a DEBUG level log `logger.debug("Invoking function: "...`

Comment: but it seems I cant even turn it off with logging.level.org.springframework.cloud=ERROR

Comment: spring-cloud-function-core 3.2.9

Comment: Something else must be enabling DEBUG level logging. .  outside of Spring, some competing configuration.

Comment: ah so it seems here the system.out.println is it https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/commit/438b8d2e237564ab3206358129ebecae2ea39cef

Comment: so i bumped spring-cloud-function-context version down to 3.2.7, now this logging is not there anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has been an issue with spring-cloud-function-context 3.2.9, I went back to spring-cloud-function-context 3.2.7 for now

Comment: Example: 

implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-context") {
        version {
            strictly '3.2.8'
        }
}